# FLUTTER: fromJson and parsedJson method not found, although import 'dart:convert';

Tags: json, flutter, dart, methods

I just started with flutter and I don't find a solution to this problem. I am currently starting off with the flutter demo provided and trying to convert this step by step to a Cupertino app.

I also used this nice [read](https://medium.com/flutter-community/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-747c46655f51) to implement JSON. However, even though I include dart:convert, the JSON methods are not found. The error is

```dart
lib/services/service_textproblem.dart:13:45: Error: Method not found: 'TextProblem.fromJson'.
  TextProblem textproblem = new TextProblem.fromJson(jsonResponse);
                                            ^^^^^^^^
lib/model/model_textproblem.dart:42:16: Error: Getter not found: 'parsedJson'.
    var list = parsedJson['taskPrmtrs'] as List;
               ^^^^^^^^^^
lib/model/model_textproblem.dart:44:12: Error: Getter not found: 'parsedJson'.
    list = parsedJson['taskTags'] as List;
           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

My service_textproblem.dart looks like this and dart:convert is not highlighted as not being used (other way around, highlighted as being used)

```dart
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:math/model/model_textproblem.dart';

Future<String> _loadTextProblemAsset() async {
  return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/textproblems.json');
}

Future loadTextProblems() async {
  String jsonString = await _loadTextProblemAsset();
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
  TextProblem textproblem = new TextProblem.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  print(textproblem.problemTasks[0].taskText);
}
```

Any ideas what I can do? I couldn't find any similar issue (except people not having included dart:convert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> fromJson and parsedJson method not found, although import
> 'dart:convert';

fromJson and parsedJson is not a property of `dart:convert` class. You need to implement those method in your Model class.
Here is an example of a Model class.

```
class Model {
  int id;
  String name;

  Model({this.id, this.name});

  Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    return data;
  }
}
```

In this class Model.dromJson function convert the json object in Model object and toJson convert the model object in json format. You need to manually add these function in your `TextProblem` class.

There are many website which convert json into data class. You can try [this](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) one.

Comment: I was not aware that fromJson and parsedJson are no library assets. Now I see the issue and am able to trace down some little bugs in the definition of both. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own `TextProblem` model class like the guideline

```
class User {
  final String name;
  final String email;

  User(this.name, this.email);

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        email = json['email'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
    {
      'name': name,
      'email': email,
    };
}
```

Comment: good point, however, would this provide the method to me? Though, what is interesting, in the "class ProblemTask" I use "factory ProblemTask.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){" In this context, fromJson is highlighted orangeish, while it remains white in the code above (which is in a different dart file)

Comment: Which error your editor showing? To save time to write this function, sometime i use this website (https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart) . Is that help you?